# (Dynamixel) Inverse rotation direction

Tags: servomotor, dynamixel

I'm wondering if there's a feature to "flip" the rotation direction with Dynamixel (I'm using MX-106). For example, if I give +1.57 to the motor, then it interprets it as `-1.57`. And the other way around.

I'm using [its ROS driver](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamixel_motor) package that doesn't seem to explicitly claim that there's a feature to do this, although there is [a question](http://answers.ros.org/question/59872/dynamixel-wheel_mode/?answer=117281#post-id-117281) where a user reported he was able to do this from source code. But I failed to replicate. So I first wanted to ask about the capability of the device itself since I don't know if the limitation comes from the Dynamixel device or from ROS driver.

Thank you.

---

(UPDATE) Usecase of mine is that I have multiple robots where the direction of how Dynamixel is attached is different per robot, and ideally like to flip the motor's direction at driver's level so that I can keep using the same controller software.

Comment: This does beg the question of why do you want to have the motor flip the direction, when surely you could flip the input to the motor yourself?

Comment: @James R I've updated my OP to answer your comment.